# Convert for loops into reduce

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, algorithm, data-structures

I have written a piece of code previously to change an object in another format. The object to change is given below:

```
{
    "testType": {
        "testCatType": {
            "testSubCat": {
                "testSubSubCat1": {},
                "testSubSubCat2": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "newType": {
        "newCat10": {
            "newCatSub1": {
                "bingo11": {},
                "bingo12": {},
                "bingo15": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "displacement": {},
....
}
```

Through my code, I change it into following format:

```
[
    {
        "label": "testType",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "testCatType",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "testSubCat",
                        "subSubCategories": [
                            {
                                "label": "testSubSubCat1"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "testSubSubCat2"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "newType",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "newCat10",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "newCatSub1",
                        "subSubCategories": [
                            {
                                "label": "bingo11"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "bingo12"
                            },
                            {
                                "label": "bingo15"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "displacement",
        "categories": []
    },
    {
        "label": "imperfection",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "metal",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "clean",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "scratched",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "dust",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "leakage",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "wipe mark",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "fingerprint",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "grunge",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "other",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "rubber",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "grain",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "stone",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "stain",
                "subCategories": []
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "surface",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "metal",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "bare",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "corroded",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "corrugated",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "gun",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "painted",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "sheet",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "treated",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "wood",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "board",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "log",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "other",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "parquet",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "plank",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "veneer",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "fabric",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "carpet",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "leather",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "pattern",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "plain",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "grass",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "artificial",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "dried",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "lawn",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "patchy",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "wild",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "concrete",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "cast in situ",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "damaged",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "dirty",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "painted",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "rough",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "slab",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "smooth",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "sand",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "beach",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "desert",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "stone",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "castle",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "cobblestone",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "floor",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "mosaic",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "terrazzo",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "wall",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "plaster",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "damaged",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "fresh",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "old",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "painted",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "soil",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "clay",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "mud",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "mulch",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "sandy",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "rock",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "cliff",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "granite",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "jagged",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "lava",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "mossy",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "rough",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "smooth",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "moss",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "ground",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "rock",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "debris",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "construction",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "nature",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "brick",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "modern",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "mortar",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "painted",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "rough",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "tile",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "ceramic",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "grout",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "pavestone",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "sidewalk",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "asphalt",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "fine",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "rough",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "torn",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "other",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "climber",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "creature",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "dirt road",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "edible",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "fur",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "paper",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "various",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "snow",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "mixed",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "pure",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "bark",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "beech",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "birch",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "oak",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "other",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "palm",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "pine",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "willow",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "gravel",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "construction",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "natural",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "pebbledash",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "marble",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "polished",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "rough",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "tile",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "ground",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "forest",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "jungle",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "other",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "roots",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "roofing",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "new",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "old",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "antique",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "asian",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "medieval",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "middle-eastern",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "roman",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "label": "coal",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "label": "brick",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    },
                    {
                        "label": "debris",
                        "subSubCategories": []
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "label": "brush",
        "categories": [
            {
                "label": "blood",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "damage",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "grunge",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "leakage",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "print",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "spatter",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "sponge",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "spray",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "stain",
                "subCategories": []
            },
            {
                "label": "traditional",
                "subCategories": []
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

The piece of code that I wrote an want to optimise is as follows:

```
let typesObj = [];
for (let type in categoryTreeV3) {
  let typeObj = {
    label: type,
    categories: []
   };
   for (let cat in categoryTreeV3[type]) {
     let categoryObj = {
       label: cat,
       subCategories: []
     };
     for (var subCat in categoryTreeV3[type][cat]) {
       if (typeof categoryTreeV3[type][cat][subCat] === "object") {
         categoryObj.subCategories.push({
           label: subCat,
           subSubCategories: _.map(_.keys(categoryTreeV3[type][cat][subCat]), value => ({ "label": value }))
          });
        }
      }
      typeObj.categories.push(categoryObj);
    }
  typesObj.push(typeObj)
}
console.log(typesObj);
```

Now I have been using reduce(), map() and filter() methods but in limited capacity but don't particularly understand how to use it for this optimisation. I'll paste my try below:

```
let test = [];
let b = [];
_.reduce(categoryTreeV3, (index, cats, key) => {
  return test.push({
    label: key,
    categories: _.reduce(cats, (i, subCat, k) => {
      b = b.concat({
        label: k,
        subCategories: subCat
       });
      return b;
    }, b)
  })
}, test);
```

But this doesn't give me intended result. Plus it is again taking me towards nesting that I wanted to avoid in the first place in order for my code to be readable. Can someone please help me in this regard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than thinking about `reduce`, this can be handled with a fairly simple recursion:

```js
const decap = ([s, ...ss]) =>
  s .toLowerCase () + ss .join ('')

const convert = (obj, depth = 0) => 
  Object.entries (obj) .map (([k, v]) => ({
    label: k, 
    ...(Object .keys (v) .length > 0 
          ? {[decap (`${'Sub' .repeat (depth) }Categories`)]: convert(v, depth + 1)} 
          : {}
       )
  }))

const input = {testType: {testCatType: {testSubCat: {testSubSubCat1: {}, testSubSubCat2: {}}}}, newType: {newCat10: {newCatSub1: {bingo11: {}, bingo12: {}, bingo15: {}}}}, displacement: {}}

console .log (convert (input))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {max-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

We start with the helper `decap`, which simply lower-cases the first letter of a string, allowing us to change `"Categories"`, `"SubCategories"`, `"SubSubCategories"`, etc., into `"categories"`, `"subCategories"`, `"subSubCategories"`, etc.

The main function, `convert` adds a `label` property for each entry in the input, using the property name as a value.  If the original value was a nonempty object we recursively call `convert` to create its subobjects, using a `depth` argument to track how many `Sub` prefixes we need to prepend to `Categories` for the current level.  Then we pass the result to `decap`.

Answer (score 4):

You can vastly simplify your logic by using a data constructor and a recursive function that uses it:

```js
const childrenName = level =>
  `${"Sub".repeat(level)}Category`.replace(/^./, c => c.toLowerCase());

const Category = level => (label, next) => {
  const obj = { label };
  const children = transform(next, Category(level + 1));
  
  if (children.length > 0)
    obj[childrenName(level)] = children;

  return obj;
};

const transform = (obj, dataConstructor = Category(0)) =>
  Object.entries(obj)
    .map(([key, value]) => dataConstructor(key, value));

const input = {
  "testType": {
    "testCatType": {
      "testSubCat": {
        "testSubSubCat1": {},
        "testSubSubCat2": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "newType": {
    "newCat10": {
      "newCatSub1": {
        "bingo11": {},
        "bingo12": {},
        "bingo15": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "displacement": {},
}

console.log(transform(input));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

For the top level, the default `MainCategory` would be used, so its children would be under `categories`. For each level down the children go under one more "sub" + "categories`.

Comment: Note that this is supposed to have `"subSubCategories"` at the third level, and presumably `"subSubSubCategores"` at the fourth, and so on.

Comment: @ScottSauyet ah you're right! I missed the "subSub" part. As always, your answer here is brilliant and inspiring. I kept the data constructor here but shifted to a mutual recursion between `Category` <-> `transform` to at least show off an alternative way to do the same operation you've done.

Comment: I love this new curried data constructor!  And your version of the initial capitalization is much nicer than mine.  Mostly I love the variety of answers people create for a single problem!